# Отложенное получение результата задачи

Tags: c#, .net

С появлением async await все стало красиво. Возьмем, например, такой кусочек кода

```
async Task Anything()
{
    var resTask = Task.Run(SomeFunction2);
    SomeAction();
    SomeFunction(await resTask);
    await SomeAction2();
    SomeAction3();
}
```

То есть тут `SomeFunction` дожидается выполнения `SomeFunction2` для того, чтобы использовать ее результат в качестве параметра.

При этом `SomeAction()` и `SomeAction3()` будут выполняться в контексте, в котором запущен `Anything()`

Но вот в версии фреймворка 4.0 отсутствуют async/await. Приходится выкручиваться. Приходится писать что то вроде этого

```
void Anything()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => 
    {
        var resTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeFunction2);
        SomeAction(); // я теряю основной контекст
        SomeFunction(resTask.Result);
        var t = new Task(SomeAction2); // я теряю основной контекст
        t.Start();
        t.Wait();
        SomeAction2(); // я теряю основной контекст
    }));
}
```

Это если без тонких нюансов (например, если SomeAction() должен выполняться в UI потоке, управление выполняемой задачей и тд. Я уже не говорю про неуправляемый таск в самом начале)

В противном случае код расползется и будет либо не лаконичным либо говнокодом. (на всякий случай скажу, что я понимаю, что в моем примере тоже говнокод, да я знаю об этом :) )

Я же хочу сделать некий билдер для построения сценариев задач. То есть, что то вроде этого

```
void Anything()
{
    var builder = new TaskBuilder();
    var res = builder.InNewContext(SomeFunction2);
    builder.InThisContext(SomeAction);
    builder.InNewContext(SomeFunction(res.Result));
    var forWaiting = builder.InNewContext(SomeAction2);
    builder.InThisContext(SomeAction3, forWaiting);
    builder.Start();
}
```

Но вот тут есть проблема

В этом месте

```
builder.InNewContext(SomeFunction(res.Result));
```

Возникнет коллапс, потому что задача еще не запущена, но включается ее ожидание для получения результата. Чутье подсказывает мне, что мне могут помочь `Expression`, но я не очень умею их готовить. В общем подскажите, осуществима ли моя задумка для фреймворка 4.0 и как лучше поступить, если осуществима?

Comment: Формально, в .net 4.0 можно использовать async/await, если подключить нюгет Microsoft.Bcl.Async и использовать соответствующую версию компилятора (5я, вроде бы).

Comment: @kmv, спасибо за инфу. А подводные камни есть? Само собой я буду изучать этот вопрос, но, может, кое что вам об этом уже известно?

Comment: использовал в одной простенькой программе для работы с сетью, вроде не было никаких проблем. Нужна была поддержка WinXP, а там только 4.0 максимум поставить можно.